# C# CLR Excecption "BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: dll, reference, clr, ref, .net-5

I am using VS 2019 Version 16.8.2
[image]

I referred a "CLR Class Library(.NET Core)" project in my "WPF App (.NET)" project and i met a exception:

```
BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'LibCLR, Version=1.0.7646.21580, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Let me first talk about how I did it.

1. Create a "WPF App (.NET)" project "TestCLR"
   [image]
2. Add a new "CLR Class Library(.NET Core)" project "LibCLR" in this solution
   [image]
3. The "common language runtime support" setting of "LibCLR"
   [image]
4. Target "TestCLR" to ".NET 5.0"
   [image]
5. "LibCLR.h" created automatically in project "LibCLR" and codes was inside

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace LibCLR {
    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

6. Add "new LibCLR.Class1();" in MainWindow.xaml.cs in project "TestCLR"

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestCLR {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            new LibCLR.Class1();
        }
    }
}
```

7. Rebuild All and debug, then i met exception
   [image]
8. Then i change the solution platform to x64 or x84, the exception were the same.
   [image]
9. It works well if i choice "WPF App (.NET Framework)" for "TestCLR" in step 1 and "CLR Class Library(.NET Framework)" for "LibCLR" in step 2

Why did not it work?
Can not i use a "CLR Class Library(.NET)" project as a project reference in a "WPF App (.NET Core)" project?
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: From screenshot: "Platform: [Active(Win32)]".  That builds the x86 (aka 32-bit) version of the DLL.  It cannot be used in a .NETCore project that runs in 64-bit mode.  Build the x64 version instead.

Comment: Hi, i tried both x86 and x64, but none works.

Comment: You can't load a .NET 5 class library into a .NET framework application, is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: But i targeted both with ".NET 5.0", is it wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the .csproj files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change Platform target to "X86" here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer is changing between x86 and x64 targets.  In a comment to your original question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025144/c-sharp-clr-excecption-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/65301239#comment115258384_6402514), you mentioned that you tried that and it didn't work for you.  So, I have a suggestion.  You are building a WPF project, and targeting dotnet 5.0. Dotnet 5.0 is OS-agnostic.  WPF is OS-specific.  It needs Windows.

Try using an OS-specific Target Framework Moniker. Open the .csproj file of both projects.  Try setting both projects to `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

Clean solution, rebuild, and test.

We've got a solution here that is dependent on Windows.  We shouldn't **have** to, but let's try explicitly targeting it. Especially that C++ project.

More reading

- [NET 5: Merging .NET Core and .NET Standard with New Target Framework Monikers (TFMs)](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2020/03/26/net-5-merging-net-core-and-net-standard-with-new-target-framework-monikers-tfms/)
- [New templates Targeting .NET 5.0](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1264967/new-templates-targeting-net-50.html)
- [Cannot compile WPF applications targeting .NET 5](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-compile-WPF-applications-targetin/1218104)